# Avoiding re-rendering of a flash object from scratch when view is reactivated

Tags: javascript, html, flash, ember.js

I have a question about div caching in ember js for views.

I am rendering a really heavy flash application as a part of a view and i want to switch between views but not necessarily have to reload the flash app from scratch. I would preferably want it to be "hidden".

Is there a way of doing this in ember
Currently i am implementing this using https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager and one of the flash apps stay on /#media and the other on /#publishing
So when user goes to /#media the media.swf gets loaded and /#publishing the publishing.swf gets loaded into the container div. Each of these routes have a corresponding view class associated to them that renders the flash object tag to be rendered.

In the past, I have used jquery to hide the container div but i am searching for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the feature you'd like is to be able to reuse a view instance and it's DOM across states. I have some ideas for how that could be done, unfortunately it's not possible right now without some nasty hacks.

Also, unfortunately with flash objects, they seem to get rerendered if you move them in the DOM or if you change their visibility. From what I can tell, to "hide" a flash object without causing a rerender, you can only move it off screen using CSS.

**Update:**

Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EE3B8/1

Unfortunately, that technique won't work for Flash objects, since moving them in the DOM will cause them to be reloaded. This would be a good way of eliminating expensive DOM creation/view instantiation.

Comment: I found that another way to hide a flash object is to set the height and width of the container div to 0, This essentially makes it hidden without causing flash player to unload the swf.

Comment: I am interesting in finding out about the hacks that you are thinking of. Maybe it might be something that i can look into.

Comment: Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EE3B8/1/

Unfortunately, that technique won't work for Flash objects, since moving them in the DOM will cause them to be reloaded. This would be a good way of eliminating expensive DOM creation/view instantiation.