# Ember.js - currentViewBinding and stop re-rendering on every view transition

Tags: ember.js

I have a statemachine and I am using the new currentViewBinding to swap out parts of an overall containerView whenever a new state is entered using currentViewBinding:

```
  index: Ember.State.create({
    enter: function(manager) {
      App.get('appController').set('feedView', Ember.View.create({
        templateName: 'dashboard_feed',
        contentBinding: 'App.feedController.content',
        controller: App.get('App.feedController')
      }));
    }
  })
```

At this moment in time, the rendering of these view is quite slow.  Is there a way I could keep the view in memory and avoid the re-rendering every time I enter the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually provided a solution to this for another question on StackOverflow, but it's super relevant here too. [Avoiding re-rendering of a flash object from scratch when view is reactivated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671745/avoiding-re-rendering-of-a-flash-object-from-scratch-when-view-is-reactivated/10775125#comment14036040_10775125)

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EE3B8/1

I extend ContainerView with a flag to stop it from destroying the currentView upon it's destruction. You'll want to stash the view instance somewhere that it won't be destroyed.

```js
App.ImmortalContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    destroyCurrentView: true,

    willDestroy: function() {
        if (!this.destroyCurrentView) { this._currentViewWillChange(); }
        this._super();
    }
});

App.immortalView = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
        'I WILL LIVE FOREVER!'
    )
});
```

​

Comment: willDestroy gets called when the whole containerview gets destroyed. I wonder if you could offer any guidance for my scenario.

I have a containerview containing a sidebar, topbar and content, all 3 of these views can change in 1 state transition.

So when the content view currentViewBinding changes, the whole containerview does not get destroyed and so willDestroy does not get called.

I don't want to render the child view of the containerview each time, I just want to hide and show it.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe this still works. After switching views although the first view still exists in memory, its state is "destroying" and its isDestroyed attribute is true, and thus it does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend Ember.ContainerView to show/hide its currentView view like so:

```js
App.FastContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  toggleCurrentViewFast: true,

  _currentViewWillChange: function() {
    var childViews = this.get("childViews"),
        currentView = this.get("currentView");

    if (this.toggleCurrentViewFast && childViews.indexOf(currentView) >= 0) {
      currentView.set("isVisible", false);
    } else {
      this._super();
    }
  },

  _currentViewDidChange: function() {
    var childViews = this.get("childViews"),
        currentView = this.get("currentView");

    if (this.toggleCurrentViewFast && childViews.indexOf(currentView) >= 0) {
      currentView.set("isVisible", true);
    } else {
      this._super();
    }
  }
});
```